# Como saber contar números repetidos em um vetor?

Tags: c, array

Estou querendo saber se há quantos valores repetidos no vetor.

Aqui está o código que tentei, porém não tive sucesso.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int a, i, j, c = 0;
  scanf("%d", &a);
  int vetor[a];
  for(i = 0; i < a; i++)
  {
     scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < a; i++)
  {
     for(j = 0; j < a; j++)
     {
         if(vetor[i] == vetor[j])
         {
            c++;
         }
     }
 }
   printf("%d\n",c);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Recomendo que use nomes mais descritivos nas suas variáveis. `i` e `j` até que são auto-explicativos devido a convenções, mas `a` poderia se chamar `quantidadeDeEntradas` e `c` poderia se chamar `repeticoesEncontradas`, por exemplo. Fica mais fácil pra quem está lendo seu código conseguir te ajudar. Além disso, explique melhor o seu problema. Dê exemplos de entradas e saídas esperadas correspondentes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do jeito que você colocou, existirão `a` casos onde `i` e `j` são iguais e portanto `vetor[i]` e `vetor[j]` são iguais, afinal de contas comparar uma posição do vetor com ela mesma sempre vai resultar em elementos iguais sendo comparados. Esse caso não é interessante e não deveria ser contado.

Outra coisa, é que contando `i` e `j`, ambos de 0 até `a - 1`, se na posição 3 e na posição 5 houver uma repetição, ela será contada duas vezes, uma com `i = 3` e `j = 5` e outra com `i = 5` e `j = 3`.

Logo, se existem `x` repetições, o seu programa está dando o valor de `2 * x + a`.

A solução para ambos os problemas é simplesmente trocar o `j = 0` do `for` interno por `j = i + 1`.

Veja o código corrigido:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int a, i, j, c = 0;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    int vetor[a];
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < a; j++) {
            if (vetor[i] == vetor[j]) {
                c++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/jmh04h)